# Wrapping widget in a row removes widget from screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a container that's half of it is a textfield and the other half is a text.

Something like this:

TEXTFIELD _________ TEXT

This is what I have, but nothing is showing on screen.
Tried using Widget inspection but it won't work on VSCode for some reason (nothing is showing in the inspector pane).

What is wrong here?

```
Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                height: 44,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xFF3A4455),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: const [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef)),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Display Name',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "USERNAME",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap your Textfield inside [**`Expanded`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [**`Flexible`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget, if you want extra space in between your Textfield and Text then add `SizedBox` or `Container` inside it, and set the width.You can set `flex` property also inside `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      height: 44,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF3A4455), 
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef)),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Display Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 20,),// if you want space then remove comment
          Text(
            "USERNAME",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of `TextField` , just wrap the `TextField` with `Expanded`.

```dart
           Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
              height: 44,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFF3A4455),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: const [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef)),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Display Name',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "USERNAME",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by InputDecorator, witch cannot have unbound width. Therefor its parent widget needs to set up the "space" that is provided to the Decorator. In this case the Text Widget. Just wrap your TextField widget in SizedBox and set it some width. (or in Expanded as provided above)

example:

```
Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
          height: 44,
          width: 300,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xFF3A4455),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef)),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Display Name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "USERNAME",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFf0f4ef),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```